# Country name based themeing system on Magento

Tags: magento

Anybody knows the trick to show different themeing for different country peoples.

For example if my store is loaded in US i want to show the us_mystore theme and the same store viewed in India then i would like to show myindia theme. How can i achieve this.

Please suggest me a idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have a "Store View" for each country/language then chose which view to use based on IP address or "Accept-Language" HTTP header. This is possible both programmatically with a module or by setting a store code from .htaccess.

**Example: Detecting language from .htaccess**
Based on [the apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) you could do something like this. It has the benefit of using the customer's preference set in their browser even when they're physically outside their country.

```
SetEnvIf Accept-Language "^en" MAGE_RUN_CODE=english
SetEnvIf Accept-Language "^hi" MAGE_RUN_CODE=hindi
```

Determining country by IP address is less accurate and needs more maintenance as IP address ranges change over time.

Comment: yeah i added to store view and each store view is having separate design now. So now how could i make the different store available for different countries through htaccess. Is there any example please

Comment: I've added a small example to give you some ideas.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to use GEO-IP in Apache if mod_geoip is installed. Then you can use country code as environment variable. Nice answer ;)

Comment: Ah, MaxMind. That's a good idea too, you should post that as a separate answer so it can be voted on.